# Ripple crashes when drawing over other apps

Tags: android, overlay, rippledrawable

I want to display a view that contains a ripple. When starting the overlay the app crashes. When removing the ripple everything works. I have added the following permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

This is the layout I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="data"
            type="MyModel" />
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:setImageBitmap="@{data.appIcon}" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{data.name}"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{data.packageName}"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</layout>
```

This is the error I got:

```
2018-11-05 17:15:36.073 10299-10299/be.vanlooverenkoen.riddle.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: be.vanlooverenkoen.riddle.app, PID: 10299
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
        at be.vanlooverenkoen.riddle.app.adapter.overlay.OverlayAppAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(OverlayAppAdapter.kt:47)
        at be.vanlooverenkoen.riddle.app.adapter.overlay.OverlayAppAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(OverlayAppAdapter.kt:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6744)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5925)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5808)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5804)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3878)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3595)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2018-11-05 17:15:36.077 10299-10299/be.vanlooverenkoen.riddle.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0301b3 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:659)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:244)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:240)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:236)
            ... 54 more
```

When removing `android:background` everything works fine.

Also when using a Switch I have the same problem. I think it has something to do with ripples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `?attr/selectableItemBackground` but no theme was set to the overlay. When using `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` everything works perfectly. Creating your own ripple drawable would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you start your app on device with API level less than 21. You need to create usual drawable with selector for api less than 21 and ripple drawable for api 21 and more.

Comment: My emulator was sdk 28 (Android pie)

Comment: And when you are using `?attr/selectableItemBackground` android will use another non-ripple drawable for min 21. So that could not be the case